# Return form input values from an HTA to a VBS script that opened it

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a VBS script that maps a drive.  Depending on the user either a generic folder (requiring no credentials) or a personal folder (requiring a username and password) is mapped.  I'm currently using standard WSH inputs for this, which obviously isn't too secure as the password is un-masked

I've looked in to solutions using `ScriptPW.dll`, but this is no longer native to Windows (I'm using Windows 7) and doesn't work when copied from XP and registered.

One solution I'm looking at now is to use an HTA to prompt for the username/password.  I've got to the point of running the file when it would be required, but I'm not sure how to (or even if I can) return the input values from the form to the parent script.

Is this possible?

**Note** - As the form is not required in all circumstances, I cannot place the whole script within the HTA.

Here is how I'm calling the HTA -

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Shell.Run("test.hta"), 1, True
Set Shell = Nothing
```

And here is the HTA -

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <title>Login Application</title>
    <hta :application
        applicationname="LoginBox"  
        border="dialog"
        borderstyle="normal"
        caption="My HTML Application"
        contextmenu="no"
        maximizebutton="no"
        minimizebutton="yes"
        navigable="no"
        selection="no"
        showintaskbar="yes"
        singleinstance="yes"
        sysmenu="yes"
        version="1.0"
        windowstate="normal" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="LoginForm">
        Enter Username: <input type="textbox" id="UserName"/><br />
        Enter Password: <input type="password" id="Password"/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Open my scans"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't return user and password to the caller. Map the drive in the HTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function **PasswordBox** can help you, just give a try ;)

```
' Just an example of how to use the function
 '
 wsh.echo "You entered: ", _
          Join(PasswordBox("Enter UID and password", _
               "Testing"), ", ")

 ' A function to present a Password dialog in a VBS (WSF) 
 ' script
 ' Requires WScript version 5.1+
 ' Tom Lavedas <tlavedas@hotmail.com>
 ' with help from and thanks to Joe Ernest and 
 ' Michael Harris
 '
 ' modified 1/2008 to handle IE7
 '
 Function PasswordBox(sPrompt,sDefault)
   set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   With oIE
 ' Configure the IE window
     .RegisterAsDropTarget = False
     .statusbar = false : .toolbar    = false
     .menubar   = false : .addressbar = false
     .Resizable = False 
     .Navigate "about:blank"
     Do Until .ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 50 : Loop
 ' Test for IE 7 - cannot remove 'chrome' in that version
     sVersion  = .document.parentWindow.navigator.appVersion  
     if instr(sVersion, "MSIE 7.0") = 0 Then .FullScreen = True 
     .width = 400       : .height = 270
 ' Create the password box document
     With .document
       oIE.left = .parentWindow.screen.width \ 2 - 200
       oIE.top  = .parentWindow.screen.height\ 2 - 100
       .open
       .write "<html><head><" & "script>bboxwait=true;</" _
            & "script><title>Password _</title></head>"_
            & "<body bgColor=silver scroll=no " _
            & "language=vbs style='border-" _ 
            & "style:outset;border-Width:3px'" _
            & " onHelp='window.event.returnvalue=false" _
            & ":window.event.cancelbubble=true'" _
            & " oncontextmenu=" _ 
            & "'window.event.returnvalue=false" _
            & ":window.event.cancelbubble=true'" _
            & " onkeydown='if ((window.event.keycode>111)"_
            & " and  (window.event.keycode<117)) or" _
            & " window.event.ctrlkey then" _
            & " window.event.keycode=0" _
            & ":window.event.cancelbubble=true" _
            & ":window.event.returnvalue=false'" _
            & " onkeypress='if window.event.keycode=13" _
            & " then bboxwait=false'><center>" _
            & "<div style='padding:10px;background-color:lightblue'>" _
            & "<b>&nbsp" & sPrompt & "<b>&nbsp</div><p>" _
            & "<table bgcolor=cornsilk cellspacing=10><tr><td>" _
            & " <b>User:</b></td><td>" _
            & "<input type=text size=10 id=user value='" _
            & sDefault & "'>" _
            & "</td><tr><td> <b>Password:</b></td><td>" _
            & "<input type=password size=12 id=pass>" _ 
            & "</td></tr></table><br>" _
            & "<button onclick='bboxwait=false;'>" _
            & "&nbsp;Okay&nbsp;" _
            & "</button> &nbsp; <button onclick=" _
            & "'document.all.user.value=""CANCELLED"";" _
            & "document.all.pass.value="""";" _
            & "bboxwait=false;'>Cancel" _
            & "</button></center></body></html>"
       .close
       Do Until .ReadyState = "complete" : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
       .all.user.focus
       .all.user.select ' Optional
       oIE.Visible = True
       CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")_
         .Appactivate "Password _"
       PasswordBox = Array("CANCELLED")
       On Error Resume Next
       Do While .parentWindow.bBoxWait
         if Err Then Exit Function
         WScript.Sleep 100
       Loop
       oIE.Visible = False
       PasswordBox = Array(.all.user.value, _
                           .all.pass.value)
     End With ' document
   End With   ' IE
 End Function
```

Comment: This works like a charm and except for the addition of some CSS to the header (Thats just me being OCD thouhg), it works out of the box. Thanks for posting.